# how to add link label to textBox control in syncfusion controls

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have developed a application using win forms. UI contains one Rich Textbox control which displays information what process is going on at background. And I save that information in notepad at specified location. I want to open that notepad from Rich Textbox control, for that I need to provide a link label in Rich Textbox along with text.

Comment: answer me please its very urgent

Comment: Do not urge! It won't give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can Add `LinkLabel` to your `RichTextBox` and handle the `linkLabel_LinkClicked` event.

**Step 1:**

Add `LinkLabel` to your `RichTextBox` Control as below:

```
 this.linkLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
```

**Step 2:**
Set few Properties as below:

```
this.linkLabel1.Name = "linkLabel1";
this.linkLabel1.Text = "Open File";
```

**Step 3:**

Add an Event Handler for `LinkClick` Event as below:

```
this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.linkLabel1_LinkClicked);
```

**Step 4:** 
Add your `LinkLabel` to `Form` as below:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.linkLabel1);
```

**Step 5:** 
Create a function `linkLabel1_LinkClicked()` to handle the `LinkClick` event as below:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C notepad.exe c:\\Data.txt";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }
```

Comment: How to add LinkLabel to RichTextBox control

Comment: just Drag & Drop on RichTextBox Control from ToolBox .

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but I take it that after you save the information to your text file, you want that "link label" or just label to open your textfile?

Just create an on-click event on that label and use Process.Start.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PathTotxtfile.txt");
```

Comment: How to add to link label to rich textbox control.

Comment: What is inside your rich textbox? Is it only the file path or are there other text inside it as well?

Comment: file path as well as other text.